# MySQL contains variable

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have an array in PHP that is looping through a set of names (and a corresponding quantity). I would like to print the ones found in a MYSQL database table (to which I've succesfully connected).  I'm currently using the code:

```
foreach ($arr as $name => $quan) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $quan." ".$row['name']. "\n";  
}
}
```

For some reason, this only prints the last quantity and name in the array.  Help?
For example, if the array has key-value pairs of {A-4, B-2, C-3}, and table contains {A, B, D} as names ... it'll only print "2 B".

Comment: stop using `mysql_query()`! use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: referring to your edit, only those does NOT exist in database will print out ?

Comment: oops, bad example, wasn't paying attention.  Fixed.

Comment: And stop producing injections. That is even possible with the deprecated `mysql_*()` (use `mysql_real_escape_string()` where appropriate) and even much simpler with the two other, non-deprecated extensions, e. g. with prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

Change the code to the following:

```
foreach ($arr as $name => $quan) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$name'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $quan." ".$row['name']. "\n";  
    }
  }
}
```

You have to loop through the result. By the way, stop using `mysql_query()`! use MySQLi or PDO instead ( and be careful of **SQL Injection** ; you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to handle input parameters ). For MySQLi implementation , here it is :

```
foreach ($arr as $name => $quan) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='$name'";
  $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());  
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $quan." ".$row['name']. PHP_EOL;  
    }
  }
}
```

And rather `"\n"`, I prefer using `PHP_EOL` ( as shown above )

---

And as the comment suggests, the SQL statement can be executed once, as follow:

```
$flipped_array = array_flip($arr); // flip the array to make "name" as values"
for($i = 0; $i < count($flipped_array); $i++) {
  $flipped_array[$i] = '\'' . $flipped_array[$i] . '\''; // add surrounding single quotes
}
$name_list = implode(',', $arr);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ($name_list)";
// ... omit the followings
```

e.g. in $arr contains "peter", "mary", "ken", the Query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('peter','mary','ken')
```

---

*sidenote*: but I don't understand your query. You only obtain the name back from the query? You can check number of rows, or you can even group by name, such as:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

to get what you want.

---

**UPDATE (again):** based on the comment of OP, here is the solution :

```
$flipped_array = array_flip($arr); // flip the array to make "name" as values"
for($i = 0; $i < count($flipped_array); $i++) {
  $flipped_array[$i] = '\'' . $flipped_array[$i] . '\''; // add surrounding single quotes
}
$name_list = implode(',', $arr);
$query = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table WHERE name IN ($name_list) GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 ORDER BY name";
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());  
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $quan." ".$row['name']. ": " . $row['cnt'] . PHP_EOL;  
  }
}
```

The above query will show the name appearing in the table only. Names not in table will not be shown. Now full codes ( be cautious of SQL Injection , again )

Comment: +1 But perhaps provide an example that groups the results rather than doing an SQL query per iteration of the array?

Comment: I don't understand.  The problem isn't that it doesn't loop through the results.  There should be either 0 or 1 result.  The problem is that each name in arr isn't printed.  Only the last name in arr is printed (or none, if the last isn't in the table).

Comment: see my edit. you are not querying `0` or `1`. What do you mean by 0 or 1 ?

Comment: The number of rows queried from the given name, if that number is 0, it shouldn't print anything.  If the number of rows is 1, it should print the name.

Comment: modified the answer , again , based on your comment .

Comment: I set $query to this?  How does it relate to the names in $arr?

Comment: see the `$name_list` definition. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: sorry, telling me to read the answer carefully doesn't help.  Where do I put this, and what is the final block of code? I'm very new to this (and for example, I don't know what "omit the followings" means). Thank you for your help.

Comment: As we see here, it is even possible to produce injection-allowing code with the new extensions :-(

Comment: @user1535846 do you ever try ? do I need to write the complete codes for you ? Anyway, full code is posted.